# neo4j errors "files was unexpected at this time" while starting

Tags: installation, neo4j

> I am using neo4j 1.9 version.
>
> > NEO4j errors files was unexpected at this time while installing the neo4j in windows 8.

Comment: What are the errors? Do you have more details?

Comment: yes i found the solution that is because of 1.9 version neo4j i am using ..if i use 1.8 version of neo4j i am not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

"files" most likely refers to "c:\program files...". The space in the path may be causing the error. Reinstall your libraries

Search for all system environment variables that contain "program files", and set them to blank before running the command to find where the error is.

execute the following command to blank out the path variable.
c:>set path=